# @ Symbol In Object Key Name Only Works In Chrome?

Tags: javascript

```
ctv.currentdate = new Date(ctv["current"]["@attributes"].attr);
```

Page works like a charm in Chrome but Firefox, IE10, & Safari all don't work. Firefox console returns the following message:

```
TypeError: ctv.current['@attributes'] is undefined
```

If I do `console.log(ctv["current"]["@attributes"]);`, Firefox returns `undefined` whereas Chrome returns an actual value, ie. `Object {attr: "2013-7-28"}`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is supporting "@", but that's technically not allowed in ES5.  Nice read: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Cool validator (if you want to explore further): http://mothereff.in/js-variables